# How does find_package(Boost) work with static and shared libraries?

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I am currently working on a project that has multiple libraries and multiple executables. Some of the executables will link some of the libraries statically and others will be linked dynamically. My question is how to go about having the option to link a library statically or dynamically using `find_package`. I noticed boost has the option to set `Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS` before calling `find_package` but I am not quite sure how Boost goes about using this. Does boost build both shared/static and then `Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS` just picks the target? Would I strictly need to use `MODULE` mode or can I use `CONFIG` mode and what would be the benefit/costs of using either mode for this kind of behaviour?

My current approach uses config mode as all a library needs to do is just call `rn_lib(<target_name>)` and everything is set up for them. I am guessing the logic to pick the static vs shared target is done in the config/find file for the library.

**Desired Behaviour**

```
set(<lib_name>_USE_STATIC_LIBS TRUE)
find_package(<lib_name> REQUIRED)
```

**Current CMakeLists.txt for libraries**

```
function(rn_lib)
cmake_parse_arguments(RN_LIB
    ""
    "NAME"
    "SRCS;HEADERS"
    ${ARGN}
)

if (RN_LIB_NAME)
    set(target_name ${RN_LIB_NAME})
else()
    set(target_name ${PROJECT_NAME})
endif()

set(static_target_option ${target_name}_STATIC)
option(${static_target_option} "Force build as static library" OFF)

set(_config_file ${target_name}_config.h)
configure_file("cmake/${_config_file}.in" ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${_config_file})

if (${PROJECT_VERSION})
    set(project_version ${PROJECT_VERSION})
else()
    set(project_version 1.0)
endif()

if (static_target_option)
    message("Build Static ${target_name}")
    add_library(${target_name} STATIC
        ${RN_LIB_SRCS}
        ${RN_LIB_HEADERS}
    )
else()
    message("Build Shared ${target_name}")
    # This could still produce a static library
    add_library(${target_name}
        ${RN_LIB_SRCS}
        ${RN_LIB_HEADERS}
    )
endif()

# setup lib variables
set(include_install_dir include)
set(include_install_abs ${RN_INSTALL_PATH}/${include_install_dir})
set(config_install_dir lib/cmake/${target_name})

set(generated_dir ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/generated)
set(version_config ${generated_dir}/${target_name}ConfigVersion.cmake)
set(project_config ${generated_dir}/${target_name}Config.cmake)

set(package_namespace RustyNail::)
set(target_export_name ${target_name}Targets)

install(
        FILES ${RN_LIB_HEADERS}
        DESTINATION ${include_install_dir}/${base_name}
)

target_include_directories(
        ${target_name}
        PUBLIC
            $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}>
            $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${include_install_dir}>
)

write_basic_package_version_file(
        ${version_config}
        VERSION ${project_version}
        COMPATIBILITY  AnyNewerVersion
)

configure_package_config_file(
        ${RN_CMAKE_PATH}/Config.cmake.in
        ${project_config}
        INSTALL_DESTINATION ${config_install_dir}
)

install(
        TARGETS ${target_name}
        EXPORT ${target_export_name}
        LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
        RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
        INCLUDES DESTINATION ${include_install_dir}
)

install(
        FILES ${project_config} ${version_config}
        DESTINATION ${config_install_dir}
)

install(
        EXPORT ${target_export_name}
        NAMESPACE ${package_namespace}
        DESTINATION ${config_install_dir}
)
endfunction()
```

**Project Tree**

```
- < root>
  - output dir
    - lib
    - bin
    - build
  - src
    - lib
      - lib1
      - lib2
    - apps
      - app1
      - app2
```

Comment: ***but I am not quite sure how Boost goes about using this*** The finder module for boost would have to handle this. https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/module/FindBoost.html

Comment: You can look at the source for this on your computer I believe it should be named `FindBoost.cmake`

Comment: @drescherjm I looked at the `FindBoost.cmake` and found it to be quite cumbersome and I was hoping for a very to the point example without all the extra options and such.